# Using a Managed-package source (github) and installing it as an Unmanaged-package

Tags: managed-package, unmanaged-package, github

I came across a managed-package on github and wanted to know if there is a way to install this on a developer org as an unmanaged-package. Insights are much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If it were on github, you'd see the source. Presumably, you could download it to a folder (clone), create a Force.com IDE project, then copy the cloned source into the Force.com IDE project. Some additional tweaking to the package.xml might be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the package.  If the package contains hard references to its managed package namespace or any code which can only be deployed into a managed packaging org such as @deprecated, you will be unable to install it into anything but the packaging org.

Another thing that can block deploying as unmanaged code is if the package.xml contains the namespacePrefix, postInstallClass, or uninstallClass elements which can only be deployed to a managed packaging org.  However, you can simply remove those elements from package.xml and deploy if that's the only holdup.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Jason Lantz, I'll give this a shot and update my findings.

Comment: Thanks you @Jason Lantz, had to edit the Package.xml and remove a few code references to the namespace which solved the issue. Thanks again!